# subquery on emailaddress not on customerid

Tags: sql-server

i want to find new vs returning customers in a given month. This query needs debugging. I want to do a case statement where it takes into email address but not customerid.

```
 SELECT
    DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate) AS Month,
    c.EmailAddress,
    (CASE WHEN exists (Select * from Orders
           where CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    and orderDate < o.orderDate) then 'Repeat' else 'New' end ) AS Customers
    FROM Customers c
        join (Orders o join OrderDetails od
                on od.OrderID = o.OrderID)
            on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
    WHERE
    o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1/1/17 00:00' AND '01/31/17 23:59'
    GROUP BY DATEPART(mm,o.OrderDate),c.EmailAddress, od.productcode,c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Can you please offer some clarification on what you mean by: "case statement where it takes into email address but not customerid."

Comment: @Robert Hartshorn yeah..This code is running fine but the only issue is it is showing those customers as new customers who have ordered before jan 2017.. but i dont want them as new customers as they are repeat customers..and the reason it is doing because all unique accounts are shown by email address and not by customerid in my database. Hope that makes some sense?

Comment: I would suspect that the lack of a table alias in the correlated subquery is going to give you problems.

Comment: @Jason A. Long then what is solution for this? And if you can suggest different way of doing same query?

Comment: @c_174, I've added an answer with an alias in the sub-query and the proper way to use date ranges, including the use of YYYY-MM-DD date format (YYYYMMDD is also good but harder to read).

Comment: @ Jason can u please explain what does SELECT 1 in subquery means?

Comment: In an "EXISTS" correlated sub-query, the engine doesn't look at columns in the select list... only the where clause. So it doesn't matter what you put in the select list. I use a "1" because it's short and because it immediately tells whoever comes after me that the value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
 SELECT
    [Month] = DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate),
    c.EmailAddress,
    Customers = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                                SELECT 1 
                                FROM dbo.Orders o2
                                WHERE o.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID AND o.orderDate < o2.orderDate
                                ) 
                    THEN 'Repeat' 
                    ELSE 'New' 
                END
FROM 
    dbo.Customers c
    JOIN dbo.Orders o
        ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    JOIN OrderDetails od
        ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
WHERE
    o.OrderDate >= '2017-01-01'
    AND o.OrderDate < '2017-02-01'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm, o.OrderDate),
    c.EmailAddress, 
    od.productcode,
    c.CustomerID;
```